# Ability to export or print reports in Tuleap that contain fields defined as HTML

Tags: tuleap

I am trying to print or export a report from Tuleap that contains fields defined as HTML.  When I use the "Printer version", then I try to Print the page, I get garbage characters.  When I try to "Export", I get HTML tags when I open the document in Excel.  Excel doesn't convert the tags to a readable format.  Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, you should report it to the developers directly in the [bug tracker](https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?tracker=140)